# Pandas - Swap Column value to another from a different dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of Football Team names

```
Names = pd.DataFrame({
         'Name': ['Adelaide', 'Central Coast','Perth' ],       
    })
```

I would like to search through another dateset and find the name and swap it with another column

```
Nameswap = pd.DataFrame({
         'Namecheck': ['Adelaide', 'Brisbane Roar', 'Central Coast','Melbourne City', 'Melbourne Victory', 'Newcastle Jets','Perth' ],       
    'BFName': ['Adelaide United', 'Brisbane Roar', 'Central Coast Mariners','Melbourne City', 'Melbourne Victory', 'Newcastle Jets','Perth Glory' ],    
    })
```

My desired output would be

```
NewNames = pd.DataFrame({
         'Name': ['Adelaide United', 'Central Coast Mariners','Perth Glory' ],       
    })
```

I have tired the following but I believe because the index is not equal in length it wont work. Is there a way round this or a different way I should be looking at.

```
key_list = list(Names['Name'])
dict_lookup = dict(zip(Nameswap['Name'], Nameswap['BFName']))
df_clean['Home'] = [dict_lookup[item] for item in key_list]
```

Comment: you can map `Names['Name'].map(dict(Nameswap[['Namecheck','BFName']].to_numpy()))` or same but `replace` instead of `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` here:

```
df = Names.merge(Nameswap, left_on=['Name'], right_on=['Namecheck'])
print(df[['BFName']])

                   BFName
0         Adelaide United
1  Central Coast Mariners
2             Perth Glory
```